# What are techniques are used to esimate the spectral properties of annealer embedding hamiltonians?

Tags: d-wave, annealing, embedding

Some information about the spectral properties of the hamiltonian of a given annealer emebedding is needed to determine a proper annealing schedule, correct?

What are methods that are used to find this spectral information?